# how to fix 'Only static members can be accessed in initializers' in Flutter Dropdown

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter. 
I am trying this example from flutter Documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Flutter Dropdown (wrapped in ListView Widget) gives error with setState by saying 'Only static members can be accessed in initializers'.Can anybody help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';

class PurchaseOrder extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PO(),
    );
  }

}

class PO extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _POState createState() => new _POState();

}

class _POState extends State<PO> {

  static String dropdownValue = 'One';

  var purchasehandle = <Widget>[

      Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
         child: Card(
           child: Container(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
             child: Form(
               child: ListView(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Text(
                    "Purchase No 1",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                   ),
                    DateTimePickerFormField(
                      inputType: InputType.date,
                      format: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                      editable: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Purchase Date',
                      hasFloatingPlaceholder: false
                      ),
                    ),

                    DropdownButton<String>(
                       value: dropdownValue,
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {

                          setState(() {    // Error Only static members can be accessed in initializers
                            dropdownValue = newValue; 
                          });
                        },

        items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          })
          .toList(),
      )

                   ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
      )
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("VIX - Purchase Order"),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2C3E50)
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: purchasehandle,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the body of widget `purchasehandle` to the widget tree itself i.e. in the `Stack` under `body`. You don't need to declare it as var.

Comment: thanks , This worked, but can I know why does it not work out side Build Method.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `dropdownValue` as static variable so either you should remove static from the declaration or use it as `_POState.dropdownValue`.

You can lear more about it [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods)